# First Android App - Google and GPS?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am a .Net developer, wanting to make my first Android app. I have installed Eclipse and am able to make the usual Hello World app. Now, my next step is a useful app (to me) which shows me geographical information based on my position.

I'm hoping it's a simple app to write, and a good primer for a first Andoid app.

I'd like to create a simple screen, which shows the nearest Suburb to my current location. So, a very basic screen, that stays on (Doesn't lock?), and simply shows me "You are in ". I'm not sure if it's possible, but it would be great if I could show, "Your nearest Railway Station is "

I'd like to ask for a tutor, or someone who could guide me, but that's pushing my luck, and am looking for pointers and ideas on how to do this. I'd then like to share it as an example of what a beginner (but experienced developer) can do with Android.

Comment: *"I'd like to ask for a tutor, .. but that's pushing my luck"* What ***is*** your question?  (And no, adding a '?' to "First Android App - Google and GPS" does **not** make it a question.)

Comment: [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html) would be good starer for you.

Comment: Andrew  -sorry, it was a bit unclear. The question really was badly worded as "I'm hoping it's a simple app to write, and a good primer for a first Andoid app", and should have been "Would it be a simple app and a good primer, and could someone point me in the right direction to start?"

Comment: Thanks Lucifer! (I never thought I would say that sentence!! :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  [This](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html) Tutorial will help you to learn Google Maps

2)  [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) Tutorial will help you in how to find current location of device.

3)  [This](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/) Tutorial will help you to find nearest places by using Google Place API

4)  [This](http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/mapOverlayDemo.html) Tutorial will help you in case if you want to show points (Overlays in android terminology) on google map.

Hope this Help.
Vipul

Answer (score 1):

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2009/11/mapview-to-center-on-current-location.html

Sorry, i missed out a 'c'. now its working :D
All the Best Again

Comment: Link seems to be bad, Vishnu.